# Building expo app is not updating the app in store

Tags: react-native, expo

I used to run expo build:android (or ios) to build and publish my react-native application.

The app in the app store automatically updated doing this.
Since I updated my expo version to 38.0.8 it doesn't seem to be working anymore?

Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you have to run

`expo build:ios(or android)`

to generate an expo build, and then run

`expo upload:ios(or android)`

to upload to the App Store or Google Play Store

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The uploading is not the problem, actually I don't want to handle this via expo, since I use Tesflight etc. The only problem now is, that the app doesn't update to the newest version when it used to update automatically.